# puppet macos x -> /usr/bin/puppet:3:in `require': no such file to load

Tags: mac-osx, puppet

Cannot use puppet on mac osx 10.8, i can find it in /usr/bin/lib but display that when i launch it :

```
/usr/bin/puppet:3:in `require': no such file to load -- puppet/util/command_line (LoadError)
from /usr/bin/puppet:3
```

Any idea ?

Edit : 
I want to use puppet in Vagrant VM to do provisioning is it the good way ?

Comment: Please ask additional questions in a separate post.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue as noted above (identical error).  I've just installed from the suggested download site, puppet 2.7.20 and factor 1.6.14.  facter presents a slightly different error message:

bash-3.2# facter
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- facter/application (LoadError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
    from /usr/bin/facter:69

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Carter

Answer (score 0):

How did you install puppet?  The native packages we provide at http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/mac/?C=N;O=A should work well with Mac OS X 10.8.  If you installed from another location, please let us know how so we can better help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes i installed this one : puppet-3.0.1-rc1.dmg